# LibGDX/OpenGL drawing seperate textures in FrameBuffer?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, framebuffer

So I am trying to combine multiple `TextureRegion`s in to one by using a `FrameBuffer`. This works extremely well when the `TextureRegion`s originate from the same `Texture` object/file but as soon as I try to combine `TextureRegion`s with different textures of origin, only the `TextureRegion`s from one texture file are drawn. The `TextureRegion`s with different textures of origin do not get drawn.

For example I have two textures:

```
Texture tex1 = new Texture(path to texture 1);
Texture tex2 = new Texture(path to texture 2);

TextureRegion reg1a = new TextureRegion(region from tex1);
TextureRegion reg2a = new TextureRegion(region from tex2);

TextureRegion reg1b = new TextureRegion(another region from tex1);
```

I set up my `FrameBuffer` like this:

```
buffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
```

In my draw method I do the following:

```
buffer.begin();
batch.draw(reg1a, x, y);
batch.draw(reg2a, x, y);
buffer.end();

batch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
```

Using the above draw method, ONLY `reg2` is drawn. reg1 does not show up at all.

```
buffer.begin();
batch.draw(reg1a, x, y); 
buffer.end();

batch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
```

Using this draw method `reg1` IS drawn, so there is nothing wrong with the textures.

```
buffer.begin();
batch.draw(reg1a, x, y);
batch.draw(reg1b, x, y);
buffer.end();

batch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
```

This draw method renders BOTH `reg1a` and `reg1b` because they both come from the same `Texture` obect/file.

What I want to be able to do is draw to `TextureRegion`s from different `Texture` objects in the same `FrameBuffer` and have them both show up.

I have tried having everything from one Texture in one FrameBuffer, and the other in another FrameBuffer, then drawing those two FrameBuffers into a new FrameBuffer, but that produces the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When are you calling `batch.end()`? If it's not before `buffer.end()` you're going to have problems.

Comment: It's inside the Stage class that the batch.end/begin are called. Should I end the batch then begin it again?

Comment: @Tenfour04 calling batch.end() before buffer.end() was called resulted in no image being drawn at all

Comment: You should be calling `batch.end()` inside `buffer.begin()` and `buffer.end()`, and then when you are done submitting the draw for the buffer's color texture, you should call `batch.end()` again. I think what's happening is you're batching sprites inside the buffer begin/end, but not actually drawing anything to the buffer because the batch doesn't know to flush itself unless you tell it to. Then those queued sprites are getting drawn directly to the screen.

Comment: @Tenfour04 This was the solution to my problem! Thanks very much!